# what is the best way to convert html to postscript? in java

Tags: java, html, css, postscript

what is the best way ( if there is any ) in java to convert html with css2 support to 
postscript file ?

Comment: http://freshmeat.net/projects/htmldoc/ is the close but written in c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you on linux? If so your best bet might be to first convert to pdf, and then use the command line utilty `pdf2ps`. According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235851/using-itext-to-convert-html-to-pdf) iText does html to pdf, although the CSS support may not be great.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is [iText](http://www.itextpdf.com/) which is a java library with support for direct HTML to PDF translation.

Comment: i need it in postscript not pdf