# How to convert HTML to PDF using iText

Tags: java, html, jsp, itext

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class GeneratePDF {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            String k = "<html><body> This is my Project </body></html>";

            OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(new File("E:\\Test.pdf"));

            Document document = new Document();
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file);

            document.open();

            document.add(new Paragraph(k));

            document.close();
            file.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code to convert HTML to PDF. I am able to convert it but in PDF file it saves as whole HTML while I need to display only text. `<html><body> This is my Project </body></html>` gets saved to PDF while it should save only `This is my Project`.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712641/java-how-to-convert-a-html-content-to-pdf-without-losing-the-formatting

Comment: I need to convert In java

Comment: [Apache open office API](http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/API/Tutorials/PDF_export#How_to_use_it_from_Java)

Comment: Any option to convert from HTML to PDF/A-2?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can do it with the [`HTMLWorker`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/html/simpleparser/HTMLWorker.html) class (deprecated) like this:

```
import com.itextpdf.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker;
//...
try {
    String k = "<html><body> This is my Project </body></html>";
    OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Test.pdf"));
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file);
    document.open();
    HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(document);
    htmlWorker.parse(new StringReader(k));
    document.close();
    file.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

or using the [`XMLWorker`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xmlworker/), (download from [this jar](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xmlworker/files/latest/download)) using this code:

```
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper;
//...
try {
    String k = "<html><body> This is my Project </body></html>";
    OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Test.pdf"));
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file);
    document.open();
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(k.getBytes());
    XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, is);
    document.close();
    file.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: But Html Worker class is not working its deprecated so can u please tell me which jar file we need for Html Workerclass?

Comment: see my update on imports

Comment: But still <html><body> This is my Project </body></html> this displaying in Pdf while i need to display only This my project only inner text of html

Comment: and something else, Deprecated means method or class is still usable, but you should not use it. It will gradually be phased out. There is a new method/class to do the same thing.

Comment: Have you changed the file path? C to E ?

Comment: Thanx I got sorry i dint change the path now i have changed and its working

Comment: One more thing i need to ask i m getting Dynamic Html on Button click i converting that Html to Pdf but its showing Error that There was Error opening this document this file already use or open by another application

Comment: Create another question and show the code and the stacktrace of it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17827136/com-itextpdf-tool-xml-exceptions-runtimeworkerexception-in-java check this My question

Comment: With XMLWorkerHelper, I'm getting `RuntimeWorkerException: Invalid nested tag head found, expected closing tag meta.`

Comment: Do you mean import com.lowagie.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker? You wrote above import com.itextpdf.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker; Where can I get that class from? Also, if I use com.lowagie.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker I always get compilation error: The type com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files. How to fix that?

Comment: It generates me an empty pdf ;/

Comment: @OndrejTokar create a question with your code and i will have a look at it

Comment: Here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29944021/converting-html-to-pdf-with-itext-library-makes-an-empty-pdf :)

Comment: You should close your resources in a finally block or use the try-with-resources construct.

Comment: Please show your imports. I can not find `PdfWriter` class in jar.

Comment: It appears HTMLWorker has been removed in iText 7

Answer (score 1):

This links might be helpful to convert.

https://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/

https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/06/26/generating-pdfs-with-flying-saucer-and-itext.html

If it is a college Project, you can even go for these,
http://pd4ml.com/examples.htm

Example is given to convert HTML to PDF

Comment: what jar file we need to add in My Project ?

Comment: You will get that help in link itself, Still go to this link, copy zip, get jar, put in buildpath : https://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/downloads/list

Comment: @Jayesh is there any solution for android, can i use this in android? do you have any idea how to convert htlm to pdf in android?