# converting a html to pdf using itext in java

Tags: java, itext, html-to-pdf

Converting a html file to pdf file. I have html file,css file and js files are in one folder 
how can i convert that index.html to create pdf using itext in java. 
can anyone help me for this issue.  is there is any sample project ?

Comment: See this. your question is duplicate

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17825782/how-to-convert-html-to-pdf-using-itext

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting HTML files to PDF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/633780/converting-html-files-to-pdf)

Answer (score 0):

You can use iTextPdf library or flying saucer (which in turns makes use of iText library). I prefer  Flying Saucer because it can convert almost all css styles  from html to pdf whereas iTextPdf is very limited in css compliant. Here is the static method I used Flying saucer to convert HTML to PDF:

```
public static void convertHtml2Pdf(String htmlPath, String pdfPath) throws   FileNotFoundException, IOException, com.lowagie.text.DocumentException {

    final ITextRenderer iTextRenderer = new ITextRenderer();

    iTextRenderer.setDocument(htmlPath);
    iTextRenderer.layout();

    /** The generated pdf will be written to the file. */
    final FileOutputStream fileOutputStream =
                new FileOutputStream(new File(pdfPath));

    /** Creating the pdf */
    iTextRenderer.createPDF(fileOutputStream);
    fileOutputStream.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a Built-in helper class called `HtmlConverter` for this use case. If you have HTML in place, then it is easy to convert it to PDF like this.

Add the following dependencies to your project.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>kernel</artifactId>
    <version>7.1.14</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>html2pdf</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

And then in  your code, you can convert the HTML files to PDF like this.

```java
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new File("./simple-input.html"),new File("simple-output.pdf"));
```

If you want to read from HTML string then you could do something like this.

```java
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf("<h1>Hello String Content!</h1>", fileOutputStream);
```

I have some detail here at my blog on [iText HTML to PDF in Java with Examples](https://springhow.com/java-html-to-pdf-conversion-using-itext-pdf/).