# Is it possible to generate a multiple page pdf file from a html page in java

Tags: java

I have a requirement to generate a multiple page pdf file from a html page in java.
For example a pdf with 2 pages, 1.order details form and 2. Return form
or some application form containing multiple pages.

If this is not possible generating multiple page pdf from html, please suggest the best way to achieve this(if not from html page). The input is an xml file, which I am parsing to get the data for html file. Please share the sample code.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using proper Java libraries.

It requires 2 steps

1. Read HTML content to some sort of intermediate result (using eg JSoup)
2. Store intermediale result as PDF (using eg. iText)

Or combine these 2 steps into one and translate on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

You can get help from this link:
[How to convert HTML to PDF using iText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17825782/how-to-convert-html-to-pdf-using-itext)
Below is an example code from the link.

Using XMLWorker:

```
try {
    String k = "<html><body> This is my Project </body></html>";
    OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Test.pdf"));
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file);
    document.open();
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(k.getBytes());
    XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, is);
    document.close();
    file.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

For the XMLWorker solution you have to download the XMLWorking jar and include it in your project

Once you create the pdf you can customize it according to your need using the itext API.
You can find a lot of itext customization examples on the internet.

Comment: Welcome To Stack Overflow! Instead of pasting a link to a solution, you should also add the relevant code from the link in your answer.  That way if the link ever goes down the answer is still available.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an XML containing all info I'd certainly perform an XSLT transformation to XSL-FO or directly to PDF.

You'll need to write an XSL-FO stylesheet and use a Java library like Apache FOP.

This strategy is often employed server-side.