# Open Source HTML to PDF in Java (2014)

Tags: java, html, pdf, converters

I've been searching high and low for an up to date solution to this age old problem.

**Long story short I want to take css + html -> pdf and do it in java.**

I don't want to use an API as the data is sensitive. Googling provides me with countless sites/services that offer to do this but I'm looking for a stand alone tool and looking for one that will work nicely from my java server. I've found [this awesome looking command line tool](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/index.html) but it's a command line tool and spawning processes off a web server starts to get sketchy IMO (but I'm always willing to hear otherwise). Additionally [flying saucer](https://github.com/flyingsaucerproject/flyingsaucer) seems to be a standard choice, but I've heard mixed reviews.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633780/converting-html-files-to-pdf) is a **5 year old question** on the subject, but I figure things have changed! Especially with all the work being done in the area of front end unit testing with dom manipulation I figure there might be some less than conventional solutions and I'm willing to hear them all!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have been working with Flying Saucer for some years now. While it does the job it often fails with various impossible to understand errors. It is highly sensitive and accepts only 100% valid strict XHTML. Be aware that it is no longer maintained! IMO it is way to sensitive/error prone and I am looking for an alternative like you - no luck so far :(

Comment: I am looking at the answer of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25574082/how-to-use-the-browsers-chrome-firefox-html-css-js-rendering-engine-to-produc it will help to anything related to html->pdf

Comment: You might try phantomjs, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37173011/1251543

Answer (score 2):

You might try a combination [CSSBox](http://cssbox.sourceforge.net) that converts HTML+CSS to SVG and then use for example Batik for creating your PDF as proposed for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875807/convert-svg-to-pdf). FlyingSaucer could also do the job.

The choice depends on your further requirements. E.g. are you processing "street HTML" or well-formed documents? What about the pages in the resulting PDF? What about interactive elements in the HTML pages?

I mean the only way is to try at least some options practically and then you may ask more specific questions about some particular problems.