# Generate PDF from JSP Page?

Tags: jsp, pdf

I have a JSP page that includes some components such as a table, images, etc.

I added a button to generate a PDF file from the current(this) page, but I didn't find any good solution for this. Any advice?

Comment: This existing answer seems to cover a lot of options:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/235851/using-itext-to-convert-html-to-pdf

Answer (score 1):

We use [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) utility to convert html page to pdf.

Answer (score 0):

May use **Big Faceless Pdf converter** .