# How do I add a PDF view to my Spring MVC (3) web app?

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, pdf, view

I have a Spring MVC webapp that generates reports using JSP/JSTL. The client is now asking that I produce a link to PDF versions of the reports, which will have slightly different layout (eg. lose pagination, navigation etc).

In my servlet context I have:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
  <property name="mediaTypes">
    <map>
      <entry key="pdf" value="application/pdf"/>
      <entry key="html" value="text/html"/>
      <entry key="json" value="application/json"/>
    </map>
  </property>
  <property name="viewResolvers">
    <list>
      <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver"/>
      <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
      </bean>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Which is taken from a tutorial somewhere. This seems to work as my old view resolver in that a GET with or without .html gets handled by my reportController (annotation request path mapping) and passed to the JSP and rendered correctly. The ReportController methods return a Strings that get resolved to JSPs.

Somehow I have to setup a PDF view that I can customise the layout of, perhaps using CSS or XSLT.

So right now a GET request to reports/basic/ or reports/basic.html will return the JSP rendering, I need to be able to do GET requests to fetch a PDF on URLs like reports/basic.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The creation of an PDF is out of the scope of Spring itself.

May you should have a look at this Stack Overflow Question: [Using itext to convert HTML to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235851/using-itext-to-convert-html-to-pdf). It discuss how to create PDFs from an HTML page, for example with [IText](http://itextpdf.com/), [Pd4mL](http://pd4ml.com/).

An other way is discussed [here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2006/jw-0410-html.html). It is based on XSTL.

*Of course, you can integrate your solution in your Spring Application, but Spring will give you not so much extra support for that task.*