# I have HTML in java string and I want to render it as a PDF. Is there any API or reference Available?

Tags: java, html, pdf, pdf-generation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting HTML files to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633780/converting-html-files-to-pdf)

I have HTML in java string and i want to render it as a PDF. 
Is there any API or reference Available for free?

Comment: This post in SO will be your answer [iText html to pdf ] [1]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/235851/using-itext-to-convert-html-to-pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Flying Saucer](http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/). It is CSS 2.1 compliant, it even covers some CSS3 features, and it uses iText under the hood. I've found it quite useful to convert XHTML to PDF.

Comment: I am getting the following error : org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.xhtmlrenderer.util.XRRuntimeException: Can't load the XML resource (using TRaX transformer). org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The declaration for the entity "HTML.Version" must end with '>'.

Comment: Take into account that Flying Saucer is an [XHTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML) renderer. Make sure your input complies the [XHTML specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/). Summarising, make it look like an XML (close every tag, like <br> and such).

Comment: That I have taken care but now I am getting NullpointerException in INFO: Class : org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer
INFO: Method : createPDF
INFO: LineNumber : 288

Comment: Can you tell us what's on line 288 of `org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer` ? Or which Flying Saucer version are you using? And maybe how are you calling the library
? (maybe it's time to start a new question)

Comment: If you're using R8, there's probably some problem with the document you're trying to convert. Maybe `_root` is null [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.xhtmlrenderer/core-renderer/R8/org/xhtmlrenderer/pdf/ITextRenderer.java/#288) ?

Comment: yes I am using R8. I don't know what is going null... The raw class is here http://grepcode.com/file_/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.xhtmlrenderer/core-renderer/R8pre2/org/xhtmlrenderer/pdf/ITextRenderer.java/?v=source

Comment: yes _root was going null one method need to be called renderer.layout(); which instantiates _root :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the complexity of your HTML code, you could give a try to iText's XMLWorker.

The project :

http://sourceforge.net/projects/xmlworker/

The demo (paste your HTML there to check what the generated PDF will look like) :

http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/

The documentation :

http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/index.html