# Convert HTML to PDF and add it to a paragraph

Tags: java, html, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I want to add a paragraph, containing HTML, to a document.
As far as I know, iText only supports adding HTML to a document directly via XMLWorkerHelper.

Furthermore I want to change the font of the HTML, but this can be done with a css-file.

My approach is similar to this code:

```
XMLWorkerHelper worker = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance();
worker.parseXHtml(pdfWriter, document, fis);
```

But this solution is writing to the document directly. I want to add the HTML to a paragraph, so I may add some additional formatting to that section.

Comment: Possible the duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/235851/using-itext-to-convert-html-to-pdf

Comment: Nearly what I need, but they only create complete documents, too. What I need is the possibility to add sections of HTML to a document. I will try to create a seperate document and merge both documents.

Answer (score 2):

```
String html = "<p>Html code here</p>";
 Paragraph comb = new Paragraph();

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(html);

ElementList list = XMLWorkerHelper.parseToElementList(sb.toString(), null);
for (Element element : list) {
    comb.add(element);
}

para = new Paragraph(comb);
cell = new PdfPCell(para);
cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
cell.setPaddingTop(0);
cell.setPaddingBottom(15f);
cell.setLeading(3f, 1.2f);

table.addCell(cell);
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to parsing [HTML step by step](http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/flatsite.html#itextdoc-menu-7). In that example, the final pipeline is a `PdfWriterPipeline` which isn't what you want (because this pipeline writes stuff to the document). You want to replace this final pipeline with an [ElementHandlerPipeline](http://api.itextpdf.com/xml/com/itextpdf/tool/xml/pipeline/end/ElementHandlerPipeline.html), converting all the HTML tags that are encountered to an [ElementList](http://api.itextpdf.com/xml/com/itextpdf/tool/xml/ElementList.html).

Once you have this list of `Element` instances, it's up to you to decide what to do with it (adding them to a `Paragraph` is one option).