# Rich text printout with itext

Tags: itext, richtext

I have user requests to add rich text input in a wicket web application to the textareas. The input text is persisted in a database. I am thinking to use one of the rich text editors out (tinyMCE, CKEditor). The problem is that there is also need for this persisted text to be printed out with itext in PDF format in some cases. Is there a straightforward way to print out html rich text to pdf? I don't mind if it's rich text or not in the printout. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you could parse the text in such a way that you look for common tags, say <strong></strong> and use String.replace to format that section into an iText bold format:    

`Font font = FontFactory.getFont("Times-Roman");
document.add(new Paragraph("Times-Roman", font));
Font fontbold = FontFactory.getFont("Times-Roman", 12, Font.BOLD);
document.add(new Paragraph("Times-Roman, Bold", fontbold));
document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);`

Comment: By the way your question seems to have been answered at http://stackoverflow.com/q/235851/1514229

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139399/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.